# Collection of AddressEntry object from Global Address List MSDN

Tags: c#, outlook

Using below code snippet i can get single addressEntry object that is 1st matched. How to get the collection of matching addressEntries objects under global address list.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.AddressList gal = app.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
Outlook.AddressEntry entry = gal.AddressEntries[name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all items in the address list to get all address entries that correspond to your requirements.

Also you may consider calling the [GetContactsFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868210(v=office.15).aspx) method of the AddressList class which obtains a Folder object that represents the Contacts folder for the AddressList object. Then you will be able to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods to find the corresponding contacts. You can read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext to retrieve Outlook Contact items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/19/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-contacts/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook Contact items using Restrict method](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/21/outlook-retrieve-contact-items/)

Comment: GetContactsFolder? For a Global Address List?

Comment: Please see the first sentence.

Comment: How is GetContactsFolder applicable to GAL? Why would OP need to consider GetContactsFolder if it always returns null for the GAL address lists?

Answer (score 0):

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you can create a `RES_PROPERTY` restriction on `PR_ANR` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/address-book-restrictions) and call `IMAPITable::Restrict` on the contents table of the corresponding `IABContainer` object. This is the same restriction used by Outlook when it resolves a name against a particular container and shows an ambiguous name dialog.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can use its [RDOSession.Addresbook.GAL.ResolveNameEx](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm) method (returns `RDOAddressEntries` collection with the matches):

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("John")
Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name
next
```