# How can I search the Outlook (2010) Global Address List for multiple names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, gal

I've read this post [How can I search the Outlook (2010) Global Address List for a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206431/how-can-i-search-the-outlook-2010-global-address-list-for-a-name) and found a working solution for getting a name from Outlook GAL.

I have 3 questions:

1. I can get the contact if the `search_string` is an email address. When it's a name, the search doesn't work. It would return `False` for resolved, but `True` for sendable. Then I get error when using `ae` object. What am I doing wrong?
2. I don't understand the code enough to modify it for searching multiple names. I simply created a for loop but maybe there is a more efficient way? For example, can I reuse the `outlook.Session` object between different searches?
3. Is the line `recipient.Resolve()` necessary?

Thanks in advance!

My attempt is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import win32com.client

search_strings = ['Doe John', 'Doe Jane']

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')

for search_string in search_strings:
    recipient = outlook.Session.CreateRecipient(search_string)
    recipient.Resolve()
    print('Resolved OK: ', recipient.Resolved)
    print('Is it a sendable? (address): ', recipient.Sendable)
    print('Name: ', recipient.Name)

    ae = recipient.AddressEntry
    email_address = None

    if 'EX' == ae.Type:
        eu = ae.GetExchangeUser()
        email_address = eu.PrimarySmtpAddress

    if 'SMTP' == ae.Type:
        email_address = ae.Address

    print('Email address: ', email_address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I found the solution so quickly after posting the question. Since it's hard to find the answer. I'm sharing my findings here.

It's inspired by [How to fetch exact match of addressEntry object from GAL (Global Address List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847029/how-to-fetch-exact-match-of-addressentry-object-from-gal-global-address-list), though it's in c# rather than python.

This method uses exact match of displayname rather than relying on outlook to resolve the name. Though, it's possible to loop through the global address list and do partial match yourself.

```
import win32com.client

search_string = 'Doe John'

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
gal = outlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = gal.AddressEntries
ae = entries[search_string]
email_address = None

if 'EX' == ae.Type:
    eu = ae.GetExchangeUser()
    email_address = eu.PrimarySmtpAddress

if 'SMTP' == ae.Type:
    email_address = ae.Address

print('Email address: ', email_address)
```

Comment: Do not ever loop through all items in GAL - some GAL containers contain 100,000 or more entries.

Comment: You are right! I just learned the lesson the hard way. But I guess I can do a binary search with the index maybe.

Comment: You can't - anything that iterates over all items is bad. Let the server do the work - either ResolveName in OOM or, if Redemption is an option, RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx

Comment: Resolve doesn’t work for me as it doesn’t even work in outlook. I’ll give the second option a try. Is there a way to search by displayname?

Comment: Sure, both Extended MAPi (PR_AND) and  RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx  in Redemption search by display name. You can then iterate over the returned list of matches.

Comment: Perfect! I’ll give those a try. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko how do I get the RDOSession object? I tried `outlook.CreateObject('Redemption.RDOSession')` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko sorry stupid question, is Redemption something I have to install for the RDOSession to work?